# How execute a trigger SQL by condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need execute a trigger **INSERT** after adding row at table **subscrubetousers** with a condition:

**subscrubetousers.SubscrubeToUsersType = 9**

```
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO logsub Set 
   LogTime = NEW.subscrubetousersTime, 
   LogIdNote = NEW.subscrubetousersId, 
   LogType = NEW.SubscrubeToUsersType;
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a condition to your trigger body:

```
BEGIN
   IF NEW.SubscrubeToUsersType = 9 THEN
       INSERT INTO logsub (LogTime,LogIdNote,LogType) 
       VALUES (NEW.subscrubetousersTime, NEW.subscrubetousersId,NEW.SubscrubeToUsersType);
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: can i know from where did this new came from ??

Comment: It not possible... what is your goal?

Comment: i have sen a similar question like this ..which uses new in triggers ..is there something to do with new in triggers ??

Comment: I still don't understand you, NEW is a reference to new record to be insert(ed) in table, you cam manipulate NEW as you need... now the question is: What is your needs/requirements/goals with this trigger?

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain please with a Trigger Update?

Comment: Do you want a trigger after delete a record on your table? in this case there is and object called OLD, it works like NEW